# can chattr +i be presented in octal format?

Tags: linux

If I have a file that was set with:

```
chattr +i
```

what is the representation of the file attributes in octal (if there is a way to represent it)?
I understand how octal works for attributes but since I make the file immutable even for the root user, what is it in octal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are unrelated to the unix file permissions that are often referred to in octal notation (which directly represents the 4-bit binary that each of the `owner`, `group`, and `other` perms require).

There is no octal notation for attributes.  They are represented by character symbols, or as `man chattr` says:

> The format of a symbolic mode is +-=[aAcCdDeijsStTu]

See the man page for details on what each of these symbols mean.

BTW, not all attributes are supported by all Linux filesystems.  e.g. `ext2`, `ext3`, and `ext4` all support the `u` (undeletable) attribute.  `xfs` does not.

Some filesystems don't support attributes at all (e.g. ZFS, vfat.  vfat will probably never support attributes, but it is on the todo list for the [zfsonlinux](http://zfsonlinux.org/) project.)

## Update

According to the [zfsonlinux issue tracker](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/229), attribute support was added in May 2014.

> Support for the obvious mappings has been merged and will be part of 0.6.3.
>
> ```
> ZFS_IMMUTABLE <-> FS_IMMUTABLE_FL
> ZFS_APPENDONLY <-> FS_APPEND_FL
> ZFS_NODUMP <-> FS_NODUMP_FL
> ```
>
> This does not cover attributes which exist on Linux but not Illumos and vise-versa.